# Directly accessed key returns error, looping through dictionary works

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dictionary, keyerror

I apologize for not being able to supply the code here, but this error is not thrown if I emulate with dictionaries of made-up data. I am open to any suggestions how to post this sort of problem in a better way.

Summary of code:
The first step is to use `pandas.read_excel` to read in data. I want to make each sheet of the excel worksheet a separate dataframe, so I am using a dictionary structure to do this in a for loop.

> 1. Create a dictionary with sheet_names (static, set in data source and manually coded) as keys and values as dataframe names (also manually coded). These lists are turned into a dictionary with "zip" function. Name `loop_dict`
> 2. Create empty dictionary `df_dict`
> 3. iterate through `loop_dict` and use `pandas.read_excel` to pull individual sheet data into dataframe values with dataframe names as keys.
> 4. Probably not pertinent to this problem, I use `.rename` and `.dropna` attributes to consistently rename the columns in the dataframes and clean up columns with NaNs. I include this step just in case someone has thrown this error due to something in these steps. I have commented out these steps, re-run the code, and still produced the same error.
> 5. Then I run two commands in a loop iterating through the dict `df_dict` (the first line is not showing up after the three reverse ticks, but it is `for k in df_dict:`):

```
for k in df_dict:
       print(k)
       print(df_dict[k].head())
  print(df_dict['WD_d18O_df'].head)
```

Through the **iteration**, the loop prints the header of all dataframes in `df_dict`. I can also access all values through the keys manually except one. That one key is `'WD_d18O_df'`, and when I try to access it **manually**, it throws the error:

```
<ipython-input-53-bdb3ae29ce28> in <module>
      3     print(df_dict[k].head())
      4 
----> 5 print(df_dict['WD_d18O_df'].head)

KeyError: 'WD_d18O_df'
```

So, this code works and finds all keys in the dictionary when looped. However, there is one key that throws an error when I attempt to access it manually.

I'm not even certain if this will ever be a problem as the rest of the code only access key, value pairs through loops. I only noticed this when checking the data structure after clean up. But I would like to understand why this is happening to avoid any future problems.

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps there's a clue in the name "WD_d18O_df" - should that be "WD_d180_df" (with a zero instead of a capital 'O')? Just a typo?

Comment: Your eyes are far better than mine, and my face is red. :)  This was in fact the source of the error. I had even copied and pasted the key name in to make sure, but I didn't go far enough back to when the key:value pair were defined, and that is where I found the error.

Comment: Happy to help, closing as a typo